# How can I locate cause of full file system if du -x doesn't show a problem?

Tags: disk-usage

DUPLICATE of  [Disk slowly filling up but no visible file size changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677778/disk-slowly-filling-up-but-no-visible-file-size-changes)

What is method for locating culprit to "full" disk?  I have nothing large on the filesystem, but "phantom files" seem to have filled up the / partition.

DU does not show where the issue is:

```
root@godzilla:/# du -hx --max-depth 1
4.0K    ./snap
15M     ./bin
17M     ./sbin
1.8G    ./usr
8.0K    ./media
6.4G    ./var
56K     ./tmp
167M    ./boot
4.0K    ./stuff
4.0K    ./srv
56K     ./home
118M    ./root
4.0K    ./mnt
8.2M    ./etc
856M    ./lib
4.0K    ./lib64
4.0K    ./opt
16K     ./lost+found
9.3G    .
```

df shows that the / partition is full!

```
root@godzilla:/# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              395M   12M  384M   3% /run
/dev/mapper/Godzilla--PC--vg-root  225G  225G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                              395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb                           687G  290G  363G  45% /stuff/drive2
/dev/sdc1                          699G  361G  338G  52% /stuff/drive3
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the folders with the largest files in `/` run `du / 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 10`. This will allow you to narrow down your search to a specific folder under `/`.

Be aware this invocation of `du` will only list folders, but will find a folder full of small files. To reveal the largest file add a `*` to the `du` command. eg. `du /* 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 10`. Also using `du -h` would confuse sort.